# How much does Charlie Harper earn?

Tags: two-and-a-half-men

Two and a half men features Charlie Sheen as a hedonistic jingle-writer.

He has a beach house in Malibu and spends a lot of money while he is rarely shown working.

So, how much does he really earn and how? Royalties?

Comment: I am asking about his earnings that allow him to sustain his extravagent lifestyle,not his net worth.

Comment: Seems to amount to pretty much the same gist though.